# create new column based on 2 columns using apply return error

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create new column based on 2 column in pandas dataframe
This is the head of the dataframe

```
    col_1   col_2
0   -0.5    H1
1   -0.5    draw
2   -0.5    H3
3   -0.5    H1
4   -1.5    H2
5   -0.5    H1
7   -2.5    H4
8   -0.5    A2
9   -0.5    H1
12  -1.5    draw
13  9.0     draw
14  -0.5    draw
15  -0.5    A1
16  -0.5    H1
17  -0.5    draw
18  9.0     draw
19  -0.5    draw
20  -0.5    H1
21  -0.5    H2
22  -3.5    A1
```

I created the function:

```
def H(d):
    if d['col_1'] == -0.5 & d['col_2'].isin(['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5+']):
        return 'W -0.5'
    elif d['col_1'] == -0.5 & d['col_2'].isin(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5+', 'draw']):
        return 'L -0.5'
    elif d['col_1'] == -1.5 & d['col_2'].isin(['H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5+']):
        return 'W -1.5'
    elif d['col_1'] == -1.5 & d['col_2'].isin(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5+', 'draw', 'H1']):
        return 'L -1.5'
    elif d['col_1'] == -2.5 & d['col_2'].isin(['H3', 'H4', 'H5+']):
        return 'W -2.5'
    elif d['col_1'] == -2.5 & d['col_2'].isin(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5+', 'draw', 'H1', 'H2']):
        return 'L -2.5'
    elif d['col_1'] == -3.5 & d['col_2'].isin(['H4', 'H5+']):
        return 'W -3.5'
    elif d['col_1'] == -3.5 & d['col_2'].isin(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5+', 'draw', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3']):
        return 'L -3.5'
    else:
        return 'und'
```

then used apply to create the new column:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(H, axis=1)
```

it returns an error:

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'isin'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

I need to create the new column with apply or any other method, but I prefer creating a function then using apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `df.col_2` is of type `string` not series
- Change **list** to **set** because Sets are significantly faster when it comes to determining if an object is present in the set.

```
def H(d):
    if d['col_1'] == -0.5 and d['col_2'] in {'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5+'}:
        return 'W -0.5'
    elif d['col_1'] == -0.5 and d['col_2'] in {'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5+', 'draw'}:
        return 'L -0.5'
   ...
```